# Cloud IDE that doesn't sleep

Tags: gratis, ide, cloud-service

I'm trying to run a chatbot online so that it will keep running regardless of my computer's state.  I figured out how to run it on Heroku, but then it needs to sleep for 6 hours each day.  I discovered codeanywhere.com, which is *almost* perfect, but the "always on" feature needs to be paid for.  Similarly, codenvy.com works as long as I'm visiting the site, but it sleeps when I leave.

What service can I use that is free and always on?

Codeanywhere.com is a perfect example of what I want, except that I need it to be constantly running.  I don't really like Heroku's style, but if there's something similar that fits the requirements, I won't complain.

In case it makes a difference, my bot is installed with pip3 and run with python3.

Comment: Good luck!! You'll likely never find this, because this gives you a free server. If you do find out, though, I'd love to hear about it (seriously).

Comment: @Mark: I've been using http://bitcoinshell.mooo.com. It's shared, so there's no sudo, but it works for me.